# Trying to define which layout should a device use

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to understand which layout uses which device.

For instance, I've different layouts:

- layout
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw720dp

> Nexus 7" (800x1280) uses layout-sw600dp
>
> Samsung GTp3100 7" (600x1.024) uses layout-sw600dp
>
> Samsung Tab 10.1 (1280x800) uses layout-sw720dp
>
> Sony XPERIA S 4.3 (1280x720) uses layout

Can you guys explain "with your words" why isn't XPERIA S using sw600dp or sw720dp? 
SW != smallest width? So smallest with from XPERIA S is 720. It should be using sw720 or sw600, right? Or am I wrong?

I've read tons of documentation, but can't understand why is this happening.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Smallest-Width qualifier refers primarily to screen size and not the physical pixels.

Using `sw720dp` for example means the device must have a minimum screen width of 720 `dp` (device-independent pixels) - this isn't about 720 physical pixels. From the documentation...

> The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen.

The physical width of the Sony XPERIA S 4.3 is 2.5" but I don't know how much of that is the actual width of the screen.

Let us pretend for the sake of calculations that the screen covers the full width...in this case to calculate `dpi` for width we simply use `720 / 2.5 = 288dpi`.

From the documentation for `dp`...

> The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160).

Rearranging the formula above to calculate `dp` we do this...

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160)
```

...this gives us the width in `dp` (and a necessary Smallest-width qualifier) of...

```
720 / (288 / 160) = 400dp
```

In short the answer is, the Sony XPERIA S 4.3 may have a high-density screen (for its size) but it isn't a large screen.

Comment: Thank you. Managed to find this out by this code:`float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
        float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;`

By the way, is there any formula to get that value "2.5", the same I get with `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`?

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán : You can use the `xdpi` and `ydpi` fields of `DisplayMetrics` to get the actual `dpi` for each dimension. Calculating physical screen size would then just be a re-arrangement of the formula I used to calculate `dpi` in my answer (e.g., `720 / 2.5 = 288 dpi` which is `px / size = dpi`) so `px / dpi = size`. From `DisplayMetrics` you would use `widthPixels / xdpi` to get the physical width of the screen.